# Why does terminal turn red after closing X?

Tags: x11, xorg, kill

My terminal's background turns red after force closing X. Why?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean your terminal emulator? How can you see it after closing X?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I added a screenshot to the main post

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Are you killing X a remote host?

Comment: Thru ctrl+alt+F1